# Creating sql statements to return information from a table

Tags: datatable, subquery, postgis, psql

I am creating sql queries to return information from a table, but I am having issues with one in particular. I want to return all of the urban areas that are in the country of colorado.
The actual definition of the query is

```
Return the names (name10) of all urban areas (in alphabetical order) that are entirely contained 
within Colorado. Return the results in alphabetical order. (64 records)
```

The tables that I am using are tl_2010_us_state10 (this stores information for the states). I think I am going to use the name10 variable in this table because that has all of the names of the states.

```
    Table "public.tl_2010_us_state10"
    Column   |            Type             |                            Modifiers                             
 ------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
  gid        | integer                     | not null default 
  region10   | character varying(2)        | 
  division10 | character varying(2)        | 
  statefp10  | character varying(2)        | 
  statens10  | character varying(8)        | 
  geoid10    | character varying(2)        | 
  stusps10   | character varying(2)        | 
  name10     | character varying(100)      |
```

Then I have a table that displays all the urban information. Once again I think I am going to use the name10 variable because it stores the name of all the urban areas.

```
                                      Table "public.tl_2010_us_uac10"
    Column   |            Type             |                           Modifiers                         
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
 gid        | integer                     | not null default 
 uace10     | character varying(5)        | 
 geoid10    | character varying(5)        | 
 name10     | character varying(100)      |
```

The code That I wrote in my sql was

```
 select a.name10 from tl_2010_us_uac10 as a join tl_2010_us_state10 as b where (b.name10 = 'colorado');
```

but I get this error

```
LINE 1: ...l_2010_us_uac10 as a join tl_2010_us_state10 as b where (b.n...
```

gid is a primary key

Answer (score 0):

You must have a join condition for an inner join. Then an order by to meet your sorting requirement.

```
select a.name10 as urban_area
from tl_2010_us_uac10 as a 
join tl_2010_us_state10 as b 
     on b.gid = a.gid
where b.name10 = 'colorado'
order by a.name10;
```

Comment: This returned 0 rows when I tried it. Im using psql does that change anything?

Comment: I am supposed to use postgis for this actually

Comment: This is standard ansi sql and should work on most any database.  I did make the assumption that gid was the relationship key.  If it is not, how do you know which urban areas are in which state?  Could it be geoid10?

Comment: I think I am supposed to use this function ST_Contains. This program is using spatial relationships

Comment: You will need to replace the on clause with the st_contains function. I am not sure that I can help further.

Comment: How would I do that? Just instead of the on function it would just be st_contains(b.gid,a.gid)

Comment: This is just a guess, but I would think you would use "on st_contains(b.gid,a.gid)"

Comment: I get this error now, lol Im so confused LINE 1: ...010_us_uac10 as a join tl_2010_us_state10 as b on st_contain...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: do you have an email I can email you with a question